# How can I make an EditText only two characters wide - also on a REAL DEVICE?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am struggeling with the difference of an EditText between any emulator and any device. The EditText does just not display the same. :-(
Can anyone tell me how I can limit an EditText to be just 2 characters wide?

What I did, I created a whole new Android project. I just pulled an EditText into my view and tried to play with all the different maxLength, maxWidth, etc. properties. The EditText would do what I want it to do in the Emulator but as soon as I have the same app on a real device the EditText is always at least 4 or 5 characters wide. Why is this??
I tried it on Android 2.2 and also 2.3

Was anyone ever managed to have an EditText which is only 2 digits wide on a real device? If yes, please let me know how. :-)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
text.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(2)});
```

Comment: I don't care about the actual number of charactes which can be entered but about the visual size of the EditText... It should be only a small two character box.

Comment: Yes, but that is not what I want. I want the EditText to be smaller

Comment: u r question looks like that, u want the text size , apply text size property.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you fix the width of the edit text and textSize of the editText...?

ex:

```
<EditText android:layout_width="5dp" andorid:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andorid:textSize="18dp"/>
```

Comment: Have you tried this on a real device? The EditText will not be 5dp wide but much more...